# Large product ∏ symbol in unicode

Tags: unicode, fonts

I am looking for large symbols in unicode like these:

```
∏ ∐ ∑ ∫
⨀ ⨁ ⨂
⊕ ⊖ ⊗ ⊘ ⊙


⎲
⎳ 

 ⌠
 ⌡
```

The only one I found is by combining two unicode symbols ⎲and ⎳. Not sure why that exists, but not a large product symbol. That's all I am really looking for (∏ over multiple lines like the sigma). If any of the other ones exist over 2 lines that would be great to know as well. Perhaps there is some way to manually make the large ∏ symbol out of smaller primitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ⎲and ⎳. Not sure why that exists

When a collection of existing glyphs is added to Unicode, it is desirable to make encoding between character sets round-trip safe. So glyphs that are duplicates or variants of each other are kept anyway.

---

As of Unicode 10, these are the greek letter pi (and its compat decompositions) available: ∏Ππϖᴨℼℿ  There are no top and bottom halves like for integral and summation.

You should not attempt to build a glyph piecewise from other glyphs shifted into position. (You said "primitives", but Unicode does not work that way.) The result is not accessible and somewhat likely to break in rendering on systems other than yours.

The correct solution is to use the ∏ glyph and simply scale up its font size. Look into [MathML](http://p3rl.org/MathML) if you are using only ad-hoc notation so far.

Comment: Except you should, if the purpose is clear. For example, rendering LaTeX to plain text for embedded code comments, or even fallback rendering for text mode browsers (where integrals, summation, and products all need to span three lines)

Comment: Rarely I've seen an engineer seen thoughtlessly create a10y problems and callously disregard the consequences. Your comment disappoints me, Pomax, I held you in better esteem.

Comment: Accessibility problem? Like what, the fact that normal people can't read LaTeX to save their life, but can read plain text formula almost immediately, so if you need to put formula in emails etc it's infinitely better? The very thing [tex2mail](https://ctan.org/pkg/tex2mail) was written for in 1992, got updates for until 2000, then got picked up by pari/gp? O_o Not everything is "do X _or_ Y", it's almost always "do both": I needed this for fallback purposes, and others may too. Which is why https://github.com/pomax/tex2utf now exists. So perhaps your conviction may need revisiting.